# MIXED_DML error only on UpsertResult has errors

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

In a `@Future` method (because of other `MIXED_DML` problems) we are upserting users and collecting the results. We then want to send an email once the transaction is complete.
If everything works well, then the users are upserted and the email is sent.
However, if there is a Database error, then the email is not sent with the following error:

```
MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): EmailMessage, original object: User: [].
```

Code:

```
List<Database.UpsertResult> userResults;
try{
    userResults = Database.upsert(userList, User.Fields.Username, false);
    System.debug(userResults);
    //if (Utils.isValidEmail(emailAddress)){
    //  sendEmail(emailAddress, userResults);
    //}
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.debug('ERROR');
    System.debug(e);
}
```

So here's the thing. If we cause the one of the users to fail on the upsert, then  we don't get to the `catch` block. The `System.debug` on line 4 prints the `UpsertResult` array, and we see that one failed and the rest succeeded.
**But** if we uncomment lines 5-7 then the `catch` block is activated and we see the `ERROR` debug lines. And that's were we see the `MIXED_DML` error with the email.
So, when everything works it can upsert users and send emails in the same transaction (only not really since it's an email queue). But if one of the records fails, the `UpsertResult` catches it no problem, but it can't push a `SingleEmailMessage` to the queue because of `MIXED_DML`.

Comment: Do you ever `setSaveAsActivity(false)`?

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Even though there is no reason why it should. There is no `targetObjectId` for the recipientList, just a plaintext email address. Answer the question and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: if using `allOrNone=false`; you should avoid the try-catch around the upsert as it will not throw an exception (assuming userList is non-null). Instead, inspect (by looping through userResults) to see which record(s) failed and take appropriate action

Comment: @cropredy Yes, I know. The try/catch is there to catch the email send error, not the upsert error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you call `setSaveAsActivity(false)` in your `sendEmail` method to avoid having it create any records.